# My father will apply for a ‘family of a settled person’ visa, can he get a refund if his application wasn't successful?

Tags: united-kingdom

This is the visa I am referring to

[Apply to join family living permanently in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk)

I can't find anything about the fees being refundable or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No,

The only circumstances where you can expect a refund are when you cancel the application *before* it is processed. Cancelled applications made in the UK are not refunded.

> You can only get your fee refunded if your application hasn’t been processed yet.

https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa

If you are applying through any third party commercial agency, the answer depends at least partly on their terms and conditions. My expectation is that they often don't refund applicants their fees even if there is a cancellation of the application.

You are not *buying* a visa, you are paying for someones time to process your application, regardless of outcome.

Comment: UK settlement visa fees are much higher than the cost of processing the application, which was reported by the home office to be in the hundreds, not thousands of pounds. The fee is more similar to an immigrant application tax than to an application processing fee. https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/606616/Unit_cost_table_2017.pdf